# How to place a div over another

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put a div on top of another.

To see what I want to achieve, check this image: https://img1.etsystatic.com/059/1/8585976/il_570xN.749758093_cccu.jpg

I want my grey left div on top of the pink header.

Here is my HTML so far:

```
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

And my CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 106%; 
    background-color: #E8D5C6;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}

#left {
    width: 15px; 
    background-color: #919191;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -8px;
}
```

This is putting my pink header on top of the grey left one, and I want it to be other way around, just like in the photo I showed you: https://img1.etsystatic.com/059/1/8585976/il_570xN.749758093_cccu.jpg

Comment: `z-index: 2` on `#left` doesn't do it?

Comment: check out `z-index` and absolute positioning. https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/z-index/

Comment: Is it not already above it? They are not overlapping in the first place, so when you use `position: relative; top:-10px` on `#left` you will see it does overlap the pink.

Comment: Any reason you cannot use a background image on `<html>` or `<body>` for the pink? Then your DIVs will overlay it by default? Are you attempting to replicate the resume for the web? You really should clarify what you are trying to achieve because it is not clear at all.

Comment: Any reason you cannot do something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/8crv7x0h/)? No absolute positioning or z-indexing. Sort of looks like what you're after.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `z-index` and `position:absolute` CSS properties. Additionally you need to also position your second `DIV` (which is on top of the other) by giving some values to `top` and `left` CSS attributes. Following is an example:

```
#first{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:1;
}
#second{
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
}
```

See this **[JSfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ukL5qhs3/)**

Answer (score 1):

[Z-index](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/z-index) makes changes on the third axis. Element with a larger z-index number will cover an element with a smaller one.

For trivia sake, default z-index of any element is `auto`, which means it inherits a value from its *parent* element. An html element has a z-index of `0`.

Edit: Check out [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1uky9tc3/1/). The #left div is above the #right one. Remove z-index property from CSS styling of a left div, and you will see that it isn't going to be above the other div no more.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite get your expected result, but here's a POC

```css
#header {
    width: 106%; 
    background-color: #E8D5C6;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
}

#left {
    width: 15px; 
    background-color: #919191;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
<div id="header"></div>
<div id="left"></div>
<div id="right"></div>
<div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

`try this example here, it was working fine you expected`http://jsfiddle.net/maheswaran/fcw043zL/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all,between **leo.fcx**'s and **Mirza**'s explanation (*"Z-index makes changes on the third axis. Element with a larger z-index number will cover an element with a smaller one"*) I did it

I didn't know what z-index was yet.

Finally I have:

```
#header {
    width: 106%; 
    background-color: #E8D5C6;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    position: absolute;
}

#left {
    width: 15px; 
    background-color: #919191;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: -8px;
    margin-top: -8px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Which works perfectly for what I wanted.